# How to get number of lines in file Git API

Tags: git, api, github

I have branch "Develop". In this branch I have file index.php.

How can I use Git Rest API to

- Get **number of lines code** of index.php file in branch Develop.
- Get **SLOC** of this file of index.php file in branch Develop.

Have any body know that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Per the [GitHub documentation,](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) there is no direct way to do this.

> Get number of lines code of index.php file in branch Develop.

1. Get the GitHub authentication token [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/).
2. Use the information [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) to get the base64-encoded contents of a file using GitHub API:

   ```
   GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
   ```

   `curl` examples:

   ```
   curl https://api.github.com/repos/google/protobuf/contents/README.md

   curl --header 'Authorization: token $GITHUB_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN' \
    --header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' \
    --remote-name \
    --location <url to the file>
   ```

   Pass the `ref` parameter for the branch. Add `?ref=branch` to the end of the URL for a specific branch.
3. Decode the base64-encoded `content` field in the response. Use `base64 --decode` if using a Linux shell. Some programming languages have a library to do this.
4. Count the number of lines in the file. Use `wc -l` if using a Linux shell. Some programming languages have a library to do this.

> Get SLOC of this file of index.php file in branch Develop.

Use [`sloccount`](https://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/) or [`cloc`](http://cloc.sourceforge.net) after step **3** above.